# VBA array storing values from wrong worksheet due to redundantly defining worksheets

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

For whatever reason, when I print `arr_in(1, 1)` it gives me the value of `arr_out(1, 1)`. Any clue as to why this might be happening?

```vb
Sub conceptos_import()
    
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim wb_in       As Workbook
    Dim wb_out      As Workbook
    Dim ws_in       As Worksheet
    Dim ws_out      As Worksheet
    Dim clls_in     As Range
    Dim clls_out    As Range
    
    Dim str         As String
    Dim str_in      As String
    Dim str_out     As String
    Dim path        As String
    
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim i_in        As Long
    Dim i_out       As Long
    
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks("rn_macros.xlsm")
    path = wb.path & "\"

    str = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Set wb_in = Application.Workbooks.Open(str)
    Set ws_in = wb_in.Worksheets(1)

    Set wb_out = Application.Workbooks.Open(path & "files\conceptos.xlsx")
    Set ws_out = wb_out.Worksheets(1)
    
    Set ws_in = wb_in.Worksheets(1)
    Set ws_out = wb_out.Worksheets(1)
        
    Dim arr_in() As Variant
    With ws_in
        Set clls_in = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr(ws_in, 1), 1))
    End With
    arr_in = clls_in.Value2
    
    Dim arr_out() As Variant
    With ws_out
        Set clls_out = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr(ws_out, 1), 1))
    End With
    arr_out = clls_out.Value2
    
    Debug.Print arr_in(1, 1)
    
    For i_out = UBound(arr_out) To LBound(arr_out) + 1 Step -1
        i = 0
        str_out = arr_out(i_out, 1)
        For i_in = UBound(arr_in) To LBound(arr_in) + 1 Step -1
            str_in = arr_in(i_in, 1)
            If str_out = str_in Then
                i = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i_in
        If i = 0 Then
            ws_out.Cells(i_out, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i_out
    
End Sub
```

All variables are properly defined in the sub (all `wb_`'s as workbooks, `ws_`'s as worksheets, `clls_`'s as ranges).

The `lr` function is a user defined function that uses the `End.xlUp` method to find last row, taking target worksheet and column as the input:

```vb
Public Function lr(ws As Worksheet, col As Long) As Long
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row
End Function
```

Comment: @braX got it. i have included the lr function now.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ws_in` inside `lr` function instead of `wsin`? Same for `wsout`

Comment: @Foxfire it should definetely be so; however, that mistake was introduced when I was formatting the example code for the post, and I can confirm that it is not this issue which is causing the problem.

Comment: Same for `arrin`/`arr_in` and `arrout`/`arr_out`. Please post actual code that compiles with `Option Explicit`.

Comment: @GSerg I have posted the actual code. Sorry for the mistakes, I was trying to format it nicely to make it easier on your eyes, and ended up changing the original code with a text replacer since I realized that the version I had made for StackO was easier to understand. This has led to some inconsistencies that I should have reviewed before posting. Apologies.

Comment: So you are deleting rows from `ws_out` where the row's first cell is not found in the column A of `ws_in`. It would appear that it's expected that some/many of the cells of those columns A will match? In particular, that `ws_in`'s A1 would equal `ws_out`'s A1, so `arr_in(1, 1)` will give you the value of `arr_out(1, 1)`?

Comment: @GSerg I made sure the data does not match, since I was in the process of testing the macro's ability to delete unmatched rows when I found this error. I was running my dataset agaisnt a row of just letter A's.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, and even though it is poorly written code, I don't understand why it was causing the arrays to misfire:

```vb
str = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Set wb_in = Application.Workbooks.Open(str)
    Set ws_in = wb_in.Worksheets(1)                     1st a

    Set wb_out = Application.Workbooks.Open(path & "files\conceptos.xlsx")
    Set ws_out = wb_out.Worksheets(1)                   1st b
    
    Set ws_in = wb_in.Worksheets(1)                     2nd a
    Set ws_out = wb_out.Worksheets(1)                   2nd b
```

As you can see the lines `Set ws_in =...` and `Set ws_out =...` are repeated. By deleting the redundant lines I was able to get it to work. The final code would look like this:

```vb
Sub conceptos_import()
    
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim wb_in       As Workbook
    Dim wb_out      As Workbook
    Dim ws_in       As Worksheet
    Dim ws_out      As Worksheet
    Dim clls_in     As Range
    Dim clls_out    As Range
    
    Dim str         As String
    Dim str_in      As String
    Dim str_out     As String
    Dim path        As String
    
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim i_in        As Long
    Dim i_out       As Long
    
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks("rn_macros.xlsm")
    path = wb.path & "\"

    str = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Set wb_in = Application.Workbooks.Open(str)
    Set ws_in = wb_in.Worksheets(1)

    Set wb_out = Application.Workbooks.Open(path & "files\conceptos.xlsx")
    Set ws_out = wb_out.Worksheets(1)
        
    Dim arr_in() As Variant
    With ws_in
        Set clls_in = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr(ws_in, 1), 1))
    End With
    arr_in = clls_in.Value2
    
    Dim arr_out() As Variant
    With ws_out
        Set clls_out = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr(ws_out, 1), 1))
    End With
    arr_out = clls_out.Value2
    
    For i_out = UBound(arr_out) To LBound(arr_out) + 1 Step -1
        i = 0
        str_out = arr_out(i_out, 1)
        For i_in = UBound(arr_in) To LBound(arr_in) + 1 Step -1
            str_in = arr_in(i_in, 1)
            If str_out = str_in Then
                i = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i_in
        If i = 0 Then
            ws_out.Cells(i_out, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i_out

End Sub
```

Comment: I did notice the repeated lines but didn't bring it up because it shouldn't be of consequence (if that is the actual code, that is). Unless of course you have some other event handlers that run after file open and rearrange the sheets. Bring the repeated lines back and add `Debug.Print ws_in.Name` / `Debug.Print ws_out.Name` after each one respectively.

Comment: This is the actual code, copied straight from VBA. There are no other event handlers that run after the file open lines. When both lines are brought back, the debug.print shows that, for some reason, both worksheets are the first worksheet of the `wb_out` book. The two target worksheets have different names so there can be no confusion.

Comment: So what you are saying is that after `Application.Workbooks.Open(path & "files\conceptos.xlsx")`, `wb_in` becomes `wb_out`, which it cannot do. Please put `Debug.Print wb_in Is wb_out` after each of the six original opening-assignment lines (from `Application.Workbooks.Open(str)` to the second `Set ws_out = wb_out.Worksheets(1)`).

Comment: Are you sure there are no events in  `Application.Workbooks("rn_macros.xlsm")`. In which workbook is the macro located?

Comment: @GSerg it returns false for every check